# De-serialisation issue with integer List when de-serialising JSON object to C# Object

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, json

The following code works fine

```
List<string> alist = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3" };
string serialisedList= (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize( alist );
List<int> deserialisedList= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<int>>( serialisedList);
```

The value of serialisedList in the above example is "[\"1\",\"2\",\"3\"]"

I then have a JavaScript object that has a property that is an array of checked CheckboxList control values. When I turn this object into JSON the key value pair looks like this:

```
{
   "SomeProp": "[\"1\",\"2\",\"3\"]"
}
```

So, basically the value here is exactly the same as the one above. However when i attempot to de-serialise this to a C# object thus:

```
public class ServerObject
{
   public List<int> SomeProp { get; set; }
}

ServerObject deserialisedObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServerObject>( jsonString );
```

I get the error:

```
Error converting value "["1","2","3"]" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]'. Path 'SomeProp'
```

Why can't the same value be deserialised into an object property as it can directly into type directly?

Answer (score 2):

You are serializing a list of STRINGS. How do you expect it to magically became list of INTS? Yes, the JSON is in general typeless and works on key-value pairs, but as for the values, it preserves the most basic format information. In JSON, there is distinction between strings and numbers (and arrays/lists and maps/objects). Look at the outputted JSON:

```
{
   "SomeProp": ["1","2","3"]
}
```

clearly, this is an array of strings.

In JSON, array of numbers looks like:

```
{
   "SomeProp": [1,2,3]
}
```

Therefore, you must first serialize it as such:

```
List<string> alist = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3" };

List<int> list2 = alist.Select(str => int.Parse(str)).ToList();
string serialisedList= (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Serialize( list2 );

List<int> deserialisedList= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<int>>( serialisedList);
```

And as for your question:

> Why can't the same value be deserialised into an object property (..)

Because the underlying value types don't match. On left side there are strings, on right side - integers. How the deserializer is to know how to do that? What if the strings were NOT base 10 integers, but base 16 integers and just so lucky that they did not use letters A-F?

and as for your second part of the question

> (..) as it can directly into type directly?

No, it cannot. If the value types don't match, any reasonable roundtrip library should throw. If your JSON-handling library allows you to assign JSON value "blargh" to an INT field/property, well, for me, that's a bug not feature :)

Comment: Even if I serialise the object to JSON as "SomeProp": "[1,2,3]" it still fails. I'm using JSON.stringify to create JSON

Comment: No. Listen to me carefully: your JSON should be `"SomeProp" : [1,2,3]`. No a single quote at right side. If you add any quotes, it will be treated as string. Your example of `"SomeProp" : "[1,2,3]"` is a string: `"[1,2,3]"` not an array of numbers: `[1,2,3]`! Indeed, I forgot quotes around key names in the map. I've fixed that. Be sure to have no quotes around the [] and no quotes around the numbers

Comment: Look here for complete example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types.2C_syntax_and_example See the PhoneNumber - it is a prop->array, and see the Age - it is an prop->integer. No quotes at any of them, except for the prop name. Similarily, an array of integers will have zero quotes.

Answer (score 0):

If you deserialize using JavaScriptSerializer, it should work:

```
List<int> deserialisedList = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<int>>(serialisedList);
```